# GCP using VM to connect to Cloud SQL via Cloud SQL Auth Proxy Private IP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am having problems connecting a *GCP* Compute Engine VM to a Cloud SQL instance configured with private IP (no public) via *Cloud SQL Auth Proxy*.

After executing

```
$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONN_NAME=tcp:3306
```

I see the following output:

```
2021/10/11 12:29:24 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {Current = 8500, Max = 1048576}

2021/10/11 12:29:28 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for *CLOUD-SQL-CONNECTION-NAME*

2021/10/11 12:29:28 Ready for new connections

2021/10/11 12:29:28 Generated RSA key in 101.010024ms
```

I haven't seen the final statement on the above on any of the tutorials I have read on this subject.

I `CTRL-C` out of the above, and I am shown:

```
^C2021/10/11 12:29:39 Received TERM signal. Waiting up to 0s before terminating.
```

I then run the below command to connect to my *Cloud SQL* instance:

```
mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1
```

which returns:

```
Enter password: (password entered)
```

that returns once the password entered:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'CLOUD-SQL-PROXY-IP-ADDRESS:3306' (22)
```

Here are some additional information:

- My VM (Ubuntu) is in the same region as my *Cloud SQL* instance, and in the same *VPC* network.
- My CLoud SQL Admin API is enabled
- The *Cloud SQL* instance is configured with only Private IP (Not public)
- I have installed the *MySQL* client in my VM
- The scope of the Cloud Access API's on my VM includes *Cloud SQL* (full access to all API's)
- Both myself and the VM's service account has Cloud SQL Admin permissions

Comment: Since you are hiding addresses, it is hard to know exactly what the commands are. Try this command: **mysql -u root -p --host localhost**

Comment: Can you only display the first digits of your IP address?

Comment: What do the `CLOUD-SQL-PROXY-IP-ADDRESS` refers to in your installation?

Comment: Why are you stopping the proxy? Are you trying to start it in a background process? By the way, the message about generating an RSA key is a recent change, so older tutorials probably won't include it.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the suggestion, however that didn't work.  The IP address I referenced with *CLOUD-SQL-PROXY-IP-ADDRESS* was the Cloud Proxy IP address returned after entering the following command ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONN_NAME=tcp:3306

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The IP address I referenced with CLOUD-SQL-PROXY-IP-ADDRESS was the Cloud Proxy IP address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @enocom I pressed CTRL-C as after the RSA message is returned to me, nothing happens.  So I CTRL-C in order to be able to launch mysql client.   I assume from your comment that you're saying CTRL-C quits the SQL Auth Proxy.   Is there something else I should use instead of CTRL-C to be able to launch mysql? Sorry if thats a rookie question I'm new to Linux/Cloud.

Comment: You must leave the proxy running. Do not CTRL-C as that kills the proxy. Open another shell window.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the guidance.   I opened a regular shell to launch the proxy.   Then separately I SSH'd into the VM and tried to launch mysql connected to the proxy.   However the same problem occurred with the same error message "Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' ".     Its just not finding the proxy.     Are there any specific firewall needs?  I didn't think so...

Comment: Localhost does not need firewall rules. You are not starting the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy correctly. Since you have been killing it, I would start by rebooting the machine. THen read the documentation again on how to start the proxy. Then connect to it. If you need more help you will need to show the IP addresses that you are using in your question, They are private addresses so showing them is not a security risk - just sow the first two numbers as in 10.1.x.x

Comment: With your last edit the error means that you have a mistake here: **-instances=INSTANCE_CONN_NAME=tcp:3306** Note flags use two dashes, you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy):

> The Cloud SQL Auth proxy does not provide a new connectivity path; it relies on existing IP connectivity. To connect to a Cloud SQL instance using private IP, the Cloud SQL Auth proxy must be on a resource with access to the same VPC network as the instance.

Which means you won't be able to access the instance unless you are in the same VPC so either you need a vm, a tunnel or a public IP.